# How do I test multiple angularjs apps with the rails jasmine gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a rails 3 app with 2 different angular apps (which also share some code) that I include in different areas of the rails app ie,

app1.js

```
//= require vendor/angular.min
//= require vendor/angular-resource

//= require app/app1

//= require services/SomeService

//= require controllers/App2SpecificController
```

app/app1.js

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var App = App || {};
  App.Controllers = angular.module('App.Controllers', []);
  App.Services = angular.module('App.Services', ["ngResource"]);

  // Make App global
  window.App = App;

  angular.module('App', [
      "App.Controllers",
      "App.Directives",
      "App.Services"
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        // some routes
    }]);
})();
```

app2.js

```
//= require vendor/angular.min
//= require vendor/angular-resource

//= require app/app2

//= require services/SomeService

//= require controllers/App2SpecificController
```

app/app2.js

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var App = App || {};
  App.Controllers = angular.module('App.Controllers', []);
  App.Services = angular.module('App.Services', ["ngResource"]);

  // Make App global
  window.App = App;

  angular.module('App', [
      "App.Controllers",
      "App.Directives",
      "App.Services"
    ])
    // No routes required
})();
```

I've set up [jasmine-gem](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem), to test one of the apps, but can't figure out how to expand that to both apps.

Some options I can think of:

- Fork jasmine-gem to be able to run with multiple `jasmine.yml` config files, and just run the tests one after another - but that feels like it could be overkill.
- Combine the apps as 1 angular app, but this would be quite difficult to do, as they work really differently (one is more angular-ly, and one is more rails-y).

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your app1 and app2 modules but still assign them to the same global var App.

```
window.app = angular.module('App1', [ ... ]);
```

and

```
window.app = angular.module('App2', [ ... ]);
```

By renaming each module, you can load each app separately in your jasmine tests.